# Is it wrong to write, I heard you save them? or Is it just a difference between American English and British English?

Tags: grammar, difference

Trunks and his parents, and Goku had travelled to the Future for some reason.
When Bulma saw Yajirobe, she said:

> Thank you. I heard you saved them.

I am wondering why it is neither

> Thank you. I heard you save them.

nor

> Thank you. I heard you that saved them.

because our English teachers used to tell us that infinitive is used without to after certain verbs of perception, such as hear and see.

Or is it just a difference between American English and British English?

Thank you.

Comment: _Hear_ in your sentence means _be told_. Your English teacher meant _hear_ in the sense of _hearing a sound_ as in _I heard them argue last night_ or _he heard John go upstairs_ adding ing to argue and go is also possible.

Comment: I think the answers didn't recognize the OP's concern. It seems there is a confusion over the use of bare infinitive after verbs _see, hear, watch, etc_. That's why he's asking why there is a past form after the verb hear and not a bare infinitive. It's the matter of sense I suppose. Please consider it in your answer to best help him/her.

Comment: **I hear** can also mean *I have been told*, or *I have heard someone say* or *the news has reached me, that...*.  *I hear the summer Olympics will be held at The North Pole in the year 2064*.  In "I heard you saved them", "you saved them" is a so-called "reduced" clause, equivalent to "that you saved them".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I heard you save them* means that you were there at the time and [over]heard what happened but didn't see it.

*I heard that you saved them* means that you got the information from someone else.

*I heard you saved them* contains an ellipsis and means the same as *I heard that you saved them*.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard you saved them.

is correct using past tense

> I heard you save them.

has a conflict in verb tenses since obviously the "saving" must occur before the "hearing".

> I heard you *that* saved them.

is incorrect since the subordinate clause is misplaced, however

> I heard *that* you saved them.
>   I heard *it was* you that saved them.

would be correct.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "I heard you save them" if the meaning is "I heard the sound you made when you saved them". "Save" in that construction is not present, but infinitive. If the meaning is "Somebody told me that you saved them", there is a finite subordinate clause (with or without 'that') and its verb "saved" needs to be in the past.